# How to configure cloudkitty in devstack

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

I need some documentation or guide which demonstrates me the installation of cloudkitty in my openstack Devstack.

I have tried installing the same using the following guide:

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/CloudKitty/Devstack

But It doesn't seems to be working.

Actually its showing error as follows while setting up itself.

I am not getting cloudkitty setted up.

When I am trying to setup using cloudkitty in following command error is occurring:

```
enable_plugin cloudkitty https://github.com/stackforge/cloudkitty master 


/opt/devstack/.localrc.auto: line 46: enable_plugin: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some necessary research I can be able to find the way for setting up the Cloudkitty in Devstack.

This is sample way of installing the same.

```
git clone git://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
cd devstack
cat > local.conf << EOF
[[local|localrc]]
# ceilometer
enable_service ceilometer-acompute ceilometer-acentral ceilometer-anotification ceilometer-collector
enable_service ceilometer-alarm-notifier ceilometer-alarm-evaluator
enable_service ceilometer-api
# horizon
enable_service horizon
# cloudkitty
enable_plugin cloudkitty https://github.com/stackforge/cloudkitty master
enable_service ck-api ck-proc
EOF
./stack.sh
```

Link for the same:
https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/CloudKitty/Devstack

But this will work only with Devstack **KILO** Version.

Reason is that enable_plugin is not supported in Version lower than KILO.

In case we need to setup the Cloudkitty in Devstack which is lower than KILO version, you can use the following Guide, which demonstrates the way of setting up the Cloudkitty in Devstack.

http://cloudkitty.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: hello,I used the same configuration but facing an error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679603/errorcloudkitty-dashboard-depends-on-openstack-dashboard-however-package-open can you have a look